# how to manage 4 or 5 API call in on create method in activity?

Tags: android

I am calling 5 API at the same time in on create method in my activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_subscription);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  
            getApplicationList1();
            getApplicationList2();
            getApplicationList3();
            getApplicationList4();
            getApplicationList5();

}
```

but it's coming to your main thread doing too much work. please help how to fix it?

Comment: You should do the long running task on the background thread and just display result on Main Thread. I see you're using Java, and if it's the REST Api, the best you can do in my opinion is to use Retrofit:

https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: I am using retrofit with the async task but however it is coming

Comment: Please share some more code, how the methods look like

Comment: And there is no need to use AsyncTask if you're using Retrofit with callbacks: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests